# array of array sort_by with nil elements (ruby)

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

I have code that sorts the way I want. By multiple fields. Cool. But now I realized that sometimes the elements could be nil.

**Q1:** Any idea how to manage to get nil values at the top of the search? And get rid of this error message `:in "<=>": undefined method "<=>" for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`

**Q2:** in the code below I sort by 3 elements can I somehow define to sort asc by e[2], decs by e[0] and asc by e[1]. I am sorting csv file and most of the fields will be text fields.

```
array_of_arrays = [[1,9,'a'],[2,2,'a'], [2,6,''], [1,3,'a'], [2,1,'']] #doesnt work
array_of_arrays = [[1,9,'a'],[2,2,'a'], [2,6,'b'], [1,3,'a'], [2,1,'b']] # works
array_of_arrays.each {|line| p line }
puts
array_of_arrays.sort_by {|e| [e[2], e[0], e[1]]} .each {|line| p line }
```

Comment: If you want the secondary sort to be "decs by e[0]," then you'll need to negate it: `sort_by { |e| [e[2].to_s, -e[0], e[1]] }`.

Comment: @Wayne Conrad: hey Wayne, why did you delete your answer???? It was such a great answer.Especially the sorting part. I was about to vote for it now ... and it's gone ....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can put `e[2].to_s` in `sort_by`. Or if it still generating error, try this:

```
e[2].nil? ? '' : e[2]
```

or

```
e[2].nil? ? ' ' : e[2]
```

or

```
e[2].blank? ? ' ' : e[2]
```

Some of those shoud work ;)

**Q2**: if column is numeric, than you can add `-` sign before that column, so:

```
 array_of_arrays.sort_by {|e| [e[2].to_s, -e[0], e[1]]} .each {|line| p line }
```

Comment: @klew: it looks so easy when one knows what he is doing... Thank you. e[2].to_s works smoothly

Comment: I added second answer. However I don't know how to inverse order of strings and other objects.